# Invoking Astyle on a string or a file via C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, astyle

I am generating C++ code via C#, for some reason after applying astyle my generated code compiles. So is there a way I can invoke astyle from within my C# windows application?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to figure out what "for some reason" is and fix it in your generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out a few days ago, so thought i would share my function to astyle via c#

'
           private void astyleDirectory(string target_path)
           {
           System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
           //Enter Path to get Astyle.exe here
 pProcess.StartInfo.FileName=System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Astyle.exe";

```
       pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--options=none --style=ansi --recursive  *.h *.cpp";
       pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
       pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
       pProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(target_path);
       try
       {
           pProcess.Start();
           string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
           string strError = pProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
           pProcess.WaitForExit();

       }
       catch { }
   }
```

'

Answer (score 0):

Astyle is a command line tool, so using Process class you can call it externally and ask it to format the C++ source file.

I have done similar projects in the past, such as

http://alex.codeplex.com